# 100% horizontal cross-browser menu HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, cross-browser, html-lists

How to make **100% horizontal cross-browser** menu HTML/CSS?
*1. with keeping clean HTML, `li` list*
*2. no image/javascript, tableless, W3C standards compliance*
[image: 100% horizontal cross-browser menu HTML/CSS example]
Example for *invalid* example:

```
/*CSS doesn't make `block` right/left space between `li` items (see attached image)*/
#nav{
    text-align:justify;
}
#nav li{ /*border:1px solid #000; margin-right:1px; margin-left:1px;*/
    display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li#span{ /*hack to make 100% horizontal*/
    display:inline-block; width:100%; height:1px;
}
*html #nav li,*html #nav li#span,*+html #nav li,*+html #nav li#span{ /*IE6/7 hacks tah are not working*/
    display:inline;
}
```

and:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home <!--unfortunately it doesn't work without space after each list, 
                                                 need for some solution--></li>
        <li>Services </li><!--don't want to add style for each list separated-->
        <li>Portfolio </li>
        <li>Clients </li>
        <li>Articles </li>
        <li>Contact Us </li>
        <li id="span"></li><!--don't like to add any extra tag (like this),
                               but other way it doesn't work,
                               need for some solution-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might get better answers on http://doctype.com/

Comment: The same question in http://doctype.com/IMB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS2.1 `table`, `table-cell` supported since IE8 and rendering improved thanks `table-layout:fixed`. Unfortunately it has layout restrictions like `margin`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

> "Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered
>   once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can
>   speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but
>   subsequent cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any
>   cell that has content that overflows uses the overflow property to
>   determine whether to clip the overflow content."

Demo http://jsbin.com/AgiMoxu/9/edit

```
<style>
ol {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
<ol>
  <li>Home
  <li>Section two
  <li>Section three
  <li>Another section
  <li>A section with a longer name
  <li>Section six
  <li>This is section seven
  <li>Section 8
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this only slightly less hacky version:

```
<style type="text/css">    
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    *display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    *display: inline;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 2px auto;
    *padding: 2px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Clients</li>
        <li>Articles</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's IE7 that causes the problems.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work on IE7/6. Do you have solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: Only Tables, unfortunately. It could be backed up with a small javascript that applies proportional widths to the elements based on the number of elements and the total width of the container.

Funny how trying to maintain IE look & feel always leads into hackiness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this, even without tables. It is not really beautiful, but works.

The trick is, that you order them as inline elements in a justified text block. The words of a justified text will do what you want with your labels. But because the last row of the justified text blocks are left-aligned, you need to end the block with a newline.

An untested example is here:

```
<style>
.label {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div style="display: block; width: 100%; text-align: justify"><div class="label">label1</div>
<div class="label">label2</div>
<div class="label">label3</div><br /></div>
```

Warning #1: it won't work, if the parent of the external div (which I don't put in this example) is width: auto .

Warning #2: you shouldn't any whitespace before the first, and after the last -s and their parents! But between the internal labels you need to have (at least one) whitespace.

Warning #3: it will put an unneeded newline after your last div. If it is a problem for you, there are multiple solutions to make it disappear, but they aren't yet better.

Comment: Your suggestion does not return the expected result, see http://jsbin.com/IWaKAGaY/1/edit